# Checking a condition for Central Limit Theorem

Tags: central-limit-theorem

This is a proof I read in a paper ().

One of the key conditions the paper wants to prove is below
\begin{equation}
s_{n}^{-2}\sum^{n}_{i=2}E\{Y^{2}_{ni}I(|Y_{ni}|>\varepsilon s_{n})\}\rightarrow 0,
\end{equation}as $n\rightarrow \infty$ for each $\varepsilon>0$.

It proves a condition 
\begin{equation}
s_{n}^{-4}\sum^{n}_{i=2}E(Y_{ni}^{4})\rightarrow 0,
\end{equation}
and claims that the latter condition implies the former condition. Can someone explain to me why？ Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that 
\begin{align}
Y_{ni}^2I(|Y_{ni}|>\varepsilon s_n)&= \varepsilon^{-2}s_n^{-2}\cdot Y_{ni}^2\varepsilon^2s_n^2I(|Y_{ni}|>\varepsilon s_n)\\
&\leqslant \varepsilon^{-2}s_n^{-2}\cdot Y_{ni}^2Y_{ni}^2I(|Y_{ni}|>\varepsilon s_n)\\
&\leqslant \varepsilon^{-2}s_n^{-2}\cdot Y_{ni}^4,
\end{align}
then take the expectation.